# Flutter change start animation on SizeTransition

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

in this code which that implemented in my application i would like to change start position of `SizeTransition` animation, but i can't any document about that

```
SizeTransition(
  sizeFactor: CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController,curve: Curves.easeInOut),
  axisAlignment: 0.0,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[

    ],
  ),
),
```

in that `SizeTransition` will start from `zero` and i want to change that to `0.5`, is any body opinion about this issue?

Comment: You should rather use `ScaleTransition`.

Answer (score 2):

To change start position you need to change offset:

```
SlideTransition(
  position: Tween<Offset>(
    begin: const Offset(-1, 0), 
    end: Offset.zero,
  ).animate(animation),
  child: child,
)


  // from left
  position: Tween<Offset>(
    begin: const Offset(-1, 0), 
    end: Offset.zero,
  ).animate(animation),


  // from right
  position: Tween<Offset>(
    begin: const Offset(1, 0), 
    end: Offset.zero,
  ).animate(animation),

  // from bottom
  position: Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(0, 1),
    end: Offset.zero,
  ).animate(animation),


  // from top
  position: Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(0, -1),
    end: Offset.zero,
  ).animate(animation),
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i try to implement this icon animations with `SizeTransition` https://imgur.com/a/5medzmM , that means delete and forward icons